# How can static_cast can cast an int to char but not reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm not sure if it has been asked earlier, but must have been I believe. Consider the simple line for start of question :

```
int a ;
char b = reinterpret_cast<char> (a);
```

I understand `reinterpret_cast` interpret the bits pattern of type x as type y, ofcouse it shouldn't work due to size mismatch and indeed it doesn't.

Now consider this another code:

```
int a ;
char b = static_cast<char> (a);
```

This works! . Now my question is how it can work ? I mean does the compiler chops off the bits? . I am certain `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` . If that, `reinterpret_cast` should also work by same technique ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a well-defined conversion from `int` to `char`; that's what `static_cast` does. In fact, you don't need the cast; you can just use an assignment here. On the other hand, `reinterpret_cast` says to pretend that the bits in an object of one type represent an object of another type; for some types that's okay (more or less), but there's no sensible way to pretend that the bits in an int can be used as the bits in a char without applying a conversion, and `reinterpret_cast` doesn't do that.

Comment: *"... and `reinterpret_cast` doesn't do that"*. which part of the spec says that?

Comment: @Nawaz, the part that defines conversions allowed by `reinterpret_cast`, obviously, where do you expect it to say it?  [expr.reinterpret.cast] "Conversions that can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_cast` are listed below. **No
other conversion can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_cast`.**"

Comment: Despite the seeming breadth of its name, `reinterpret_cast` is quite limited. As @JonathanWakely points out, there's a list of things it can do (basically things involving pointers and references) and nothing else is allowed. 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast]. Not at all like a C-style cast...

Answer (score 5):

static_cast can either force a defined conversion to happen or it can reverse a defined conversion (other than for adding or removing const/volatile).   You think that reinterpret_cast is some super cast that can do anything.   That is not the case.  It has a set of defined conversions.

It can convert pointers of one type to a pointer of another (as long as const/volatile is preserved).  It can similarly do so for references.   It can cast pointers to integral types and vice versa.

Other than that, it does NOT do anything and your program is not well-formed.